# troubleshooting scribe for social api authentication

Tags: java, scribe

I just started looking at scribe for authentication with social networks such as twitter/facebook etc.  I am using the example for twitter as reference.  However, I don't seem to get oauth_verifier from twitter for some reason (even though the callback is registered through the service builder - I am using localhost in the callback as it worked with another social api).  Any helpful suggestions would be quite welcome.  thanks in advance.

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
.provider(TwitterApi.class)
.apiKey(consumerKey)
.apiSecret(consumerSecret)
.callback("http://localhost/oauth/twitter")
.build();

        //get the token
        Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

        String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        Logger.info("authurl::" + authUrl); // not getting the oauth_verifier
```

**Debug output from scribe** (*I changed the token info*):

```
setting oauth_callback to http://localhost/oauth/twitter
generating signature...
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Foauth%252Ftwitter%26oauth_consumer_key%3DAAACCCV6ASDFGHJCgYBCD%26oauth_nonce%3D607134093%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1353965859%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: +mSqKJIC1Q0pMEFs/gIJViF7kbg=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> http://localhost/oauth/twitter , oauth_signature -> +mSqKJIC1Q0pMEFs/gIJViF7kbg= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 607134093 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> AAACCCV6ASDFGHJCgYBCD , oauth_timestamp -> 1353965859 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 200
response body: oauth_token=itJrpOP3KLeD7Ha6oy0IRr4HysFut5eAOpIlj8OmNE&oauth_token_secret=X8LmhAUpvIkfEd7t7P1lvwwobC3JJIhUabcEs0Rn5w&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
authurl::https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=itJrpOP3KLeD7Ha6oy0IRr4HysFut5eAOpIlj8OmNE
obtaining access token from http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
setting token to: Token[itJrpOP3KLeD7Ha6oy0IRr4HysFut5eAOpIlj8OmNE , X8LmhAUpvIkfEd7t7P1lvwwobC3JJIhUabcEs0Rn5w] and verifier to: org.scribe.model.Verifier@55ac8c3d
generating signature...
```

Update:
I am able to receive the oauth_verifier now.  I will update this post once I am done testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pilot error mostly.  I was able to get oauth working with twitter using scribe.  After getting the service, the request Token from the service & then the authorizationUrl from the service (while passing in the request token), I was able to redirect to the authorization URL.  Once there, I was able to authenticate myself against twitter using my twitter ID which redirected me to the callback URL specified when I created the service.  Upon authentication, I received the oauth_verifier which I was able to use to create the verifier & then receive the access token from the service using the verifier and the request token.  Then the oauth request was made & signed which resulted in the response from twitter with the user details.  Worked.  Hope it helps.